# Flutter TextField: hide suggestion bar on iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

How can I hide the suggestion bar on the iOS keyboard when using the `TextField`? I have tried to use the following arguments, however,  did not yield the desired result:

```dart
autocorrect: false, 
enableSuggestions: false,
smartDashesType: SmartDashesType.disabled, 
smartQuotesType: SmartQuotesType.disabled,
```

I discovered that setting the `keyboardType` to `TextInputType.name` helped when testing on the simulator, but I am uncertain about potential side effects and how it will function on a real iOS device.

Are there any solutions that could provide a better approach to hiding the suggestion bar in this scenario?

Flutter version is **3.3.2**

[image]

Comment: It happens on android too?

Comment: @MarceloArthur Yes, this happens on Android too. But currently client wants to hide suggestion bar on iOS only.

Comment: You are using all the properties that de docs and other StackOverflow suggests. Maybe if you update your Flutter version and packages? Idk